# Efficient way to eliminate isolated vertices and reorder the vertices of resulting graph

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, graph-theory

Quite a mouthful for a title, but here goes. I'm faced with the problem of reading a bunch of undirected edges and a number of vertices from an input stream and outputting a set of edges. The set of edges that I'm outputting can't have any 'blanks' - what I mean by this is that I cant have an edge set of (1,2), (2, 4) and (4, 5) as vertex #3'd never be mentioned in the vertex set.

[image: Not allowed]

*This graph wouldn't be allowed as 2 would be a "blank"*

[image]

*This graph is allowed as there are no "blanks" in the connected graph. There are 4 vertices, and they're numbered 1 through 4.* The output from this graph would be [[1, 3][3, 4][4, 2][2, 1]]

How I've gone about this as of yet is the following:

When I learn how many vertices there are, I add all their indices to a HashSet containing all isolated vertices.
As I read the edges from the input stream, I remove both the vertices of every edge from the HashSet.
After that I add them to a 2D-array with dimensions (|V|, 2). 
If there are any isolated vertices after I've taking in all the edges, I call on my "reorder-method".

What it does is the following;

- Takes the 2D-matrix and the set of isolated vertices as input
- Calls on my help-method findMatrixProperties() which finds the max value of the matrix aswell as the number of distinct vertices by iterating over the whole matrix one element at a time through a nested loop.
- Then I enter my while loop with (while matrixMax > nrOfVertices)
- In my while loop I iterate over the whole matrix, substituting all the max-values to the minimum value of the HashSet with the isolated vertices.
- After I've done a full iteration of the matrix, I remove the minimum in the isolated vertex set and call to findMatrixProperties() again.

In pseudo this is (the program itself is written in Java)

```
reorderMethod(matrix M, isolated vertex set I) 
  matrixProperties = findMatrixProperties(M) // matrixProperties is an instance of a helper class MatrixProperty which holds two integers, max and nrOfVertices
  while (max > nrOfVertices) 
    for row in M
      for col in M 
        if M[col, row] = max:
          M[col, row] = min(I)
    // Remove min(I) from I 
    matrixProperties = findMatrixProperties(M)
```

Are there any ways I could make this more efficient somehow?

Comment: I'm confused as to why that second graph is allowed - isn't there a "blank" in the sense that 5 is never mentioned?

Comment: Hmm, maybe a bit misleading. It is accepted as I won't output 5, I only output the connected 'parts' of the graph.

Comment: Also, why can you have the edge (1, 2) in your edge set in the first graph given that that's not an edge in the graph?

Comment: Can you provide an output for the second *allowed* graph?

Comment: I don't have that edge in the first graph. Those are separate examples. Sure thing.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko, added the output

Comment: What will you output for a graph with 5 vertices and a single [1, 2] edge?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko only [[1, 2]]

Comment: So I can see that you only allow the graph to have a single component with edges where vertex indices are consecutive and start at 1, don't you?

Comment: It's fine if there are several components, but every vertex that I output has to be connected to atleast one other vertex for it to be accepted. And yes, the vertex indices have to be consecutive and start at 1.

Comment: You can iterate over every edge in your graph and flag the vertices being in its ends as **marked**. Then iterate over the vertices in order from `1` to `nVertices` making sure that first comes a group of **marked** vertices and the rest is **not marked**. If condition satisfies you may output every edge in your graph, otherwise your graph is unacceptable.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of already do that though. As I write in my question I add all the vertices to the HashSet of isolated vertices at the start, and then I iterate over the edges removing both end-vertex of every edge from that set. Then I have a set containing all isolated vertices. The problem that I need help with is making an accepted instance from an unaccepted one (that is, if a vertex that has index < max index is isolated)

Comment: Ok, let's say you have a boolean array where you **mark** the vertices. After you've **marked** all vertices at the ends of the edges **mark** array will possibly contain altering series of `true`/`false` values for unacceptable graph. Make graph acceptable by simply **swapping** the vertices. Use two pointers, first points to the first position of `false` (unmarked) value and is **increasing**, second points to the last position of `true` (marked) value and is **decreasing**. Swap the vertices of two pointers and move the pointers. Do it until the first will be behind the second one.

Comment: After swap make sure to move each pointer to its next corresponding `true`/`false` value. (may require to increment/decrement several times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find a canonical renumbering for the vertices of a graph such that no completely unconnected node has a smaller label than a connected node.

The simple answer is to label each vertex with the count of connected vertices with smaller labels. (That will number the vertices starting at 0 rather than 1, but you could add one to every label easily enough.)

You seem to be using a boolean NxN array rather than adjacency lists, so that's how I wrote the following pseudocode. The change for adjacency lists would be trivial, though.

What we is to first reduce the boolean array to an boolean vector by applying an `or` operator over every row. A node is connected to something unless its entire row is false, so the boolean vector is sufficient to tell us whether a node is connected or not. Obviously, we can stop when scanning a row when we hit the first `true` value. We then reinterpret the boolean vector as an integer vector of 0s and 1s, and do something very similar to a cumulative sum over the vector, so that the vector will contain for each entry the number of connected components with smaller labels, which means that the resulting vector is precisely the translation from old labels to canonical labels if you ignore the unconnected vertices. (It's possible to construct the translation for all the vertices; the pseudocode below will do that by renumbering unconnected vertices from the last label down.)

I've used a python-like pseudocode because Java isn't pseudo enough for me :)

```python
# M is an adjacency matrix; we assume that it is square.
# The function returns the translation vector
def renumber(M):
  ones = 0
  zeros = len(M) - 1
  trans = []
  for row in M:
    if any(row):
      # the edge is connected
      trans.append(ones)
      ones += 1
    else:
      # the edge is unconnected
      zeros -= 1
      trans.append(zeros)
  return trans
```